# Equilibrium in Electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, equilibrium

In case of electrostatics,from [Earnshaw's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) we get that we can't put a charge in a stable equilibrium with mere electrostatic forces, which is pretty logical as for being consistent with Laplace Equation the X and Y both Partial derivatives can't be simultaneously negative.
But on the other hand, if we have a charged Ring with uniform charge density and place a test charge of different polarity small enough not to disturb the electrostatic field due to the ring and put it close to the centre of the ring on the axis of it then it performs small oscillations about the centre. Clearly it is in a stable equilibrium so where is the fallacy? The region of interest i.e. an imaginary small cylinder with the axis same as the axis of the ring with diameter less than the radius of the ring is totally free of charge too so that it must follow laplace equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charge is unstable within the plane of the ring. If it is given a small nudge it will accelerate toward the ring.

Comment: So why is it oscillating if pushed in axial direction?isn't it violating earnshaw theorem?

Comment: @user157588 Earnshaw's Theorem implies stability in all directions, not just in the axial direction.  A system which is stable with respect to perturbations in one direction but not another is unstable.

Comment: Ok got it,i was confusing it with minima in one particular plane's intersection with potential field

Answer (score 2):

The charge is unstable within and above the plane of the ring. If it is given a small nudge it will accelerate toward the ring, even if it is isolating In the axial direction.